# Auto-save textarea every so many seconds

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I need help with "auto-saving" a textarea. Basically, whenever a user is typing in the textarea, I would like to save a "draft" in our database. So for example, a user is typing a blog post. Every 15 seconds I would like for the script to update the database with all text input that was typed into the textarea.

I would like for this to be accomplished thru jQuery/Ajax but I cannot seem to finding anything that is meeting my needs.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"];
$answer=$_GET["a"];

//Connect to the database
require_once('mysql_connect.php') ;

$sql="UPDATE english_backup SET q".$q."='".$answer."' WHERE student_id = {$_COOKIE['student']} LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

?>

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str, answer)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser_english.php?q="+str+"&a="+answer,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like ajax... I'm using ajax jQuery so you will need  [jQuery Library](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) for it to work. Download it. You can find tutorials on the documentation tab of the website.

```
 //in your javascript file or part
$("textarea#myTextArea").bind("keydown", function() {
        myAjaxFunction(this.value) //the same as myAjaxFunction($("textarea#myTextArea").val())
});

function myAjaxFunction(value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "yoururl.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "textareaname=" + value,
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data) {
                alert("unable to save file!");
            }
        }
    });
}

 //in your php part
 $text = $_POST["textareaname"]; 
 //$user_id is the id of the person typing
 $sql = "UPDATE draft set text='".$text."' where user_id='".$user_id."'"; //Try another type of query not like this. This is only an example
 mysql_query($sql);
 if (mysql_affected_rows()==1) {
    echo true;
 } else echo false;
```

Hey everyone I'm still having a problem please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050785/php-parse-html-using-querypath-to-plain-html-characters-like-facebook-twitter

Comment: Hey Peter thanks for the reply. How often would this save the textarea?

Comment: don't forget to add the function saveText() by Elliot Bonneville above

Comment: if you add something like "setTimeout(myAjaxFunction(), 15000);" this will have to be processed every 1.5 seconds. BUt if you want something like when the user types try something: $("#myTextArea").bind("keydown", function() { myAjaxFunction(this.value); });

Comment: I am sorry I am not too good with javascript. The Ajax code you posted, what is that functions name? What is the myAjaxFunction? Sorry but thanks for your help!

Comment: oops sorry... I'm using jQuery.. you can learn it here: "http://jquery.com/". You need the jquery library for it to work. http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery. I will edit my answer.

Comment: No problem at all. I have jQuery already included on my page. Thanks I will be looking for the update

Comment: Or you can just link to the [jQuery file hosted on Google's CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) rather than downloading it which is better.

Comment: @Nathan sometimes I get error when I use the hosted link. I usually download it so its much easier.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. So I added this code to my page and so far it has not worked. However, I believe I might have done one part wrong. The #myTextArea, is this the ID attribute of the textarea? Or is it the name attribute of the textarea?

Comment: in jQuery, ".name" is for class and "#name" is for id. dots are for classes and hashes are for ids. I think you might want something like <textarea id="myTextArea" name="myTextArea"></textarea> if "this.value" doesn't work try $(this).val(). the this will give you the element which is the textarea.

Answer (score 6):

```
function saveText() {
    var text = $("#myTextArea").val();
    // ajax call to save the text variable

    // call this function again in 15 seconds
    setTimeout(saveText, 15000);
}();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I copy and pasted this code on my page, how would I save the user input to my database?

Comment: @three3: That depends on the architecture of the rest of your project. What you're asking is a pretty vague question, probably to vague to answer properly right now. If I were you, I'd research it, attempt to implement a solution on your own, then come back here if you run into any problems on the way.

Comment: I have researched and tried many "solutions" that I have found online but none of them seem to work properly. I have accomplished what I am trying to do on input boxes and radio buttons but I am not able to figure this out for the textarea inputs. I am using PHP on my page along with some jQuery.

Comment: Well, what do your PHP calls look like?

Comment: I have added my javascript and PHP code to the original post. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May you please tell me should I use textarea-value in database or localstorage? *(I mean is about autosaving)*